# What determines SiteLinks with search bar vs SiteLinks with no search bar?

Tags: seo, sitelinks

When we type [w3schools](https://www.google.com/search?q=w3schools) in Google, this is displayed:

[image]

It seems like these stuff are called "Google Sitelinks". Why is it that some sitelinks have a search bar while others don't? :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like with the Sitelinks Google decides if it will add it or not. The criteria is not public and you do not have any control over whether it will appear or not. Although having built in search functionality in your site probably helps out a whole lot I am sure.

Comment: While we do not have control over it, what are some factors that may come into play?